# No response from my webhook on Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

This is the code I have in my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const appExpress = express().use(bodyParser.json());

const {
  dialogflow,
  Image,
} = require('actions-on-google')

const app = dialogflow()

appExpress.post('/hook', express.json() ,(req, res) => {

  app.intent('MyIntent', conv => {
    conv.ask('Hi, how is it going?')
  });

});

appExpress.listen(3333, ()=>console.log("Server is live at port 3333"));
```

When I run this, it returns no errors (I see the message "server is live..") and also when I send a message to my bot with the intent "MyIntent" I get no error, but also no response..

If I look at the Diagnostic Info, under the Fulfillment Status there is this error:

> Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the implemented webhook service to fulfill the documented [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#requirements)?

Comment: Yes @Nick_Kh, it actually works fine when I use the "dialogflow-fulfillment" library for returning a response. But now I need to use the "actions-on-google" library and I don't get what I need to change to make it work..

Comment: Does this answer your question? Its an actionsSdk example, but the Dialogflow integration should work the same way. You should set the Dialogflow object to handle the req, res parameters. [Create actions-on-google object from Express request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409333/create-actions-on-google-object-from-express-request)

Comment: Hi @Jordi, I tried that but now I'm getting the error "Handler not found for handle name"
But the name I used is actually the name of one of my intents..

Comment: @onaizit, can you share the code that you've used to retrieve req,res parameters finished with error in up comment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that google library is supposed to work, but generally when using express, you most close the HTTP request by sending a response, there are several examples here

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

You could try adding this after `convo.ask`

`res.sendStatus(200);`

Comment: Thank you CommonCoreTawan, but I don't think that one is the problem. The response should be sent by the google library when I add the response message for the intent. The thing is that it doesn't even enter the app.intent block (if I put a console log inside there it doesn't print it)

Comment: Try removing express.json from the post route. Maybe it's getting stuck in that Middleware

Comment: How are you sending the request? via the browser, some code, etc? Please edit your question and show that.

Comment: The code I showed is the complete code for my file called "index.js". Then on Dialogflow I specified the URL of my webhook server, so every time I send a message to my chatbot, Dialogflow sends a request to my server